# 500 error after apply SUPEE-10570 patch in magento 1.9.1.0 enabled complier

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-10570

My magento version is ver. 1.9.1.0.

We saw a blank page at /checkout/cart after applying SUPEE-10570 and compiling. Just to clarify: With deactivated compiler all things went well, with activated compiler we only could see a blank cart page when logged in without any log entries (even after activating all possible logs and developer mode).

Cause:

the function getPasswordTimestamp will invoke two times when visit /checkout/cart.

disabled compiler both invocation work.

enable compiler only the first invocation work, second invocation failed.

can anyone explain the give the good solution?

Comment: Check in the console while adding the product to the cart.

Comment: there is no error log in php_error_log or error_log file.

Comment: no check in firebug network console...Add  ini_set("display_errors",1) in index.php

Comment: the function getPasswordTimestamp will invoke two times when logged in and visit /checkout/cart.

disabled compiler both invocation work.

enable compiler only the first invocation work, second invocation failed.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to relaunch complation process and not only activate it.

If you use OPcache/APC/... it is recommended to purge their cache too.

Do not forget to refresh Magento cache after that.

Comment: refresh all cache and relaunch complation process. no error in log, only get a blank page when add to cart. but works if disable complation

Comment: the function getPasswordTimestamp will invoke two times when logged in and visit /checkout/cart.

disabled compiler both invocation work.

enable compiler only the first invocation work, second invocation failed.

Comment: Ok, so my answser is useless. I encouter same issue on 1.9.0.1, 1.7.0.2,1.9.2.4. Maybe buggy patch.